# Get xpath for radio button with label and title as arguments

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I need to get xpath for radio button. I have to get this radio button by the text that is contain in cell 1st argument, and choose proper option by the text in option (Disabled, Enabled)

```
<tr cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<td>
<span class="1st argument">Ctx fix: </span>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1">
<span class="second argument">Enabled</span>
<input type="radio" value="0">
<span class="second argument">Disabled</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath which contains the [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) and [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) axes.

```
"//span[contains(text(), 'Ctx fix:')]/following::span[text()='Disabled'][1]/preceding-sibling::input[1]"
```